# Редирект функции print в lua (перевод с С на Delphi)

Tags: delphi, lua

Есть код на С, который описывает редирект функции print из lua (lua5.1.dll) на свой обработчик. Помогите перевести его на Delphi?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lua.hpp"

static int l_my_print(lua_State* L) {
    int nargs = lua_gettop(L);
    std::cout << "in my_print:";
    for (int i=1; i <= nargs; ++i) {
        std::cout << lua_tostring(L, i);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg printlib [] = {
  {"print", l_my_print},
  {NULL, NULL} /* end of array */
};

int main(void) {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_getglobal(L, "_G");
    luaL_setfuncs(L, printlib, 0);
    Lua_pop(L, 1);
    luaL_dostring(L, "print(\"Hello from Lua\")");
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

PS. Обертку для работы ЛУА взял отсюда https://github.com/danieleteti/lua4delphi

Comment: Буквально сегодня на SO была просьба переписать на другой язык программирования. Привожу ответ в моём вольном переводе:
"Если вам действиетльно нужно, чтобы кто-то сделал эту работу для вас, то обратите внимание на freelance-сайты, где люди получают оплату за выполнение подобных задач. Если же вы хотите выполнить задачу самостоятельно, то не стесняйтесь показывать уже сделанное. И задавайте более конкретные вопросы."

Comment: @Ruslan Rakhmanin Руслан, УВАЖАЕМЫЙ поищете в интернете анекдот про программистов, чем отличается Русский, Еврейский и Англ форум. Без комментариев.  Ответ на свой же вопрос я привел ниже.

Comment: @ИндиПутный не менее УВАЖАЕМЫЙ, вам все верно сказали. С заданиями - на фриланс. С сформулированными вопросами - сюда. Также рекомендую вам либо привести вопрос к вашему ответ, либо наоборот. Т.к. сейчас у вас все в "лучшем" виде русских форумов - Спросили А, ответили "все не так, делайте Y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо ни чего переписывать, при использование обвертки https://github.com/danieleteti/lua4delphi нужно всего лишь вызвать функцию:

```
LuaBind.DeclareGlobalFunction('print',printL);
```

которая перенаправит вызов функции print на наш обработчик.

а сама функция printL будет выглядеть так:

```
function printL(L: PLua_State): Integer; cdecl;
```

.......

```
function printL(L: PLua_State): Integer;
var
  N, I                                : Integer;
  S                                   : MarshaledAString;
  Sz                                  : Size_t;
  Msg                                 : String;
begin
  Msg := '';

  N := lua_gettop(L);  //* number of arguments */
  lua_getglobal(L, 'tostring');

  for I := 1 to N do
    begin
      lua_pushvalue(L, -1);  //* function to be called */
      lua_pushvalue(L, i);   //* value to print */
      lua_call(L, 1, 1);
      S := lua_tolstring(L, -1, @Sz);  //* get result */
      if S = NIL then
      begin
        Result := luaL_error(L, '"tostring" must return a string to "print"',[]);
        Exit;
      end;

      if I > 1 then
        Msg := Msg + #9;
      Msg := Msg + String(S);
      lua_pop(L, 1);  //* pop result */
    end;

  Result := 0;

  // тут указываем метод который выведет наше сообщение
  ХХХХХ.DoPrint(Msg);
end;
```

Comment: Если сравнивать ваш код с кодом на С, то видно несоответствие. В коде на С просто последовательно со стека снимаются значения аргументов функции при помощи `lua_tostring(L, i)`. У вас же для сначала в стек добавляется глобальная функция `tostring`. Потом для каждого аргумента вашей функции печати он кладётся в стек и вызывается функция `tostring`, положенная ранее. Результат выполнения через `lua_tolstring(L, -1, @Sz)` наконец получается в Delphi. Зачем 2 раза вызывается `tostring`, сначала внутренняя, потом внешняя. Почему нельзя было как в С просто получить аргументы со стека?

Comment: Кстати, проверку на корректное выполнение `lua_tolstring` уже делать бесполезно. Если бы она была, то уже сработала бы при выполнении встроенной в Lua глобальной  `tostring`.
Или я прочитал код? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Эти два кода сравнивать не надо. Реализацию вызова print взял из готового решения - другого проекта: https://github.com/Dennis1000/verysimplelua из файла VerySimple.Lua.pas . За замечания по коду спасибо, буду разбираться. PS. На данный момент все работает как и планировалось.